# How do I find a point with this property?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $A,B,C$ points on $\mathbb R^3 $ such that $A=(2,2,2–\sqrt{2}), B=(0,2,2–\sqrt{2}), C=(2,2–\sqrt{2},2)$.

Let $\pi$ be the plane passing through $A,B, C$ and let $\pi+$ be the subspace determined by that plane containing origin. Let $r$ be the orthogonal line to $\pi$ passing through A. How can I find a point D on the line r at distance 2 from A and contained in $\pi+$?

i know how to write equation of the plane and $r$  but I don't know how to use the condition given by $\pi+$ and finding a point $D$ with this property.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you mean 'contained in $\pi+$'?

Comment: @UmeshShankar    yes that's my fault I'll correct. really thanks

Comment: Are you working in vector form or coordinate form?

Comment: I use the classical cartesian coordinate form

Comment: Write the equation of the plane as $ax+by+cz=d$ for $d>0$. The 'semispace' with the origin is the set of $(x,y,z)$ such that $ax+by+cz<d$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok  so now I can find the equation of the line  r  in parametric form is $x=at+x_0$  $y=bt+y_0$ $z=ct+z_0$ with  $x_0,y_0,z_0,a,b,c in  $ \mathbb R$ so the point D on r is  (at+x_0,bt+y_0,ct+z_0) use the formula to find DA (distance) , find 2 values of t and then choose the best ?